# Automatically link a depreciating accounting book to a fixed asset when creating a new fixed asset record in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, accounting

I have a ticket to see why a specific subsidiary (international to the U.S.) does not create the Statutory Accounting Book automatically when the record is created. The any other international subsidiary does create the secondary accounting book when a record is created, but this particular one is not populating automatically.

[FAM Depreciation History tab should look like this when record is submitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEjU7.png)

When I looked at the Accounting books, that international subsidiary is listed on there. Also, when I look at the subsidiary itself, I see that it has that Accounting book on it. Nothing stands out as to why they have to manually add the FAM depreciation. I am expecting it to populate when the record is created regardless of the subsidiary used.